# If object array has x parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, if-statement

I have object array:

```
obj = {
 name : "john doe",
 phone : "123456789"
};
```

I want to check if there is an "email" parameter.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have this ability. It looks like you need [VanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: just use `for in`

Comment: `console.log('email' in obj)`

Comment: ty guys and sorry for my question duplicate